# Grid alignment inside canvas in C#

Tags: c#, canvas, grid, windows-phone

I am working on a Windows Phone project, that requires me to dynamically place a grid inside a canvas along with 2 Textblocks showing relevant data.

My code looks something like this.

```
            Canvas canvas = new Canvas();
            canvas.Height = height;
            canvas.Width = width;

            Grid grid = new Grid();
            grid.Height = height;
            grid.Width = width;
            grid.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green);
            grid.ShowGridLines = true;
            canvas.Children.Add(grid);

            ColumnDefinition c1 = new ColumnDefinition();
            c1.Width = GridLength.Auto;
            ColumnDefinition c2 = new ColumnDefinition();
            c2.Width = GridLength.Auto;

            grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(c1);
            grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(c2);

            TextBlock wel_txt = new TextBlock();
            wel_txt.Text = wel.ToString();
            wel_txt.TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center;
            wel_txt.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
            wel_txt.FontSource = slkscr;
            wel_txt.FontFamily = new FontFamily(FontName);
            wel_txt.FontSize = FontSize;

            TextBlock tel_txt = new TextBlock();
            tel_txt.Text = tel.ToString();
            tel_txt.TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center;
            tel_txt.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
            tel_txt.FontSource = slkscr;
            tel_txt.FontFamily = new FontFamily(FontName);
            tel_txt.FontSize = FontSize;

            grid.Children.Add(wel_txt);
            grid.Children.Add(tel_txt);
            Grid.SetColumn(tel_txt, 0);
            Grid.SetColumn(wel_txt, 1);

            canvas.Children.Add(grid);
```

Ideally, the code should create 2 columns in the canvas, and place each textblock in a column. Perfectly aligned. But what I get is both textblocks overlapping each other on the top left corner of the canvas.

What am I missing?

Comment: What framework is this? WPF?

Comment: Its on Windows Phone > Silverlight > so yes - WPF.

Comment: Have you tried using a `StackPanel` instead of a `Grid` ?